# Azure API Management: WADL document does not contain 'resources' element

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-api-management

I am trying to create API using Azure API Management service. For this I have a service which is deployed to Azure web server and returns XML response as shown below:
[XML Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nLIx.png)

I am trying to integrate this endpoint on Azure API management service instance, but getting error as shown below: [Error on adding endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPy0h.png)

I am fairly new to this, and need help about the cause of the issue and what other things that I have missed. Also, what kind of end point can we give the API field when creating API

Comment: Are you trying to import REST based API ?

Comment: The URL that you specify on second screenshot, does it return WADL document or data this XML Response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing your API, you need to provide the URL which could return the **specification** of your API(not the URL of your API). As you choose [WADL format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language), please provide a URL which could return specification of your API as following format.

```
<resources base="http://xx.domain.com/api/">
  <resource path="newsSearch">
    <method name="GET" id="search">
      <request>
        <param name="p1" style="query" type="xsd:int" default="1"/>
        <param name="p2" style="query" type="xsd:string" default="abc"/>
      </request>
      <response status="200">
        <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="yn:ResultSet"/>
      </response>
      <response status="400">
        <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="ya:Error"/>
      </response>
    </method>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

If your API is created by ASP.NET Web API, you could generate swagger format specification using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle). Then you could import your API specification by choosing Swagger format.